# gtrendsR Error: widget$status_code == 200 is not TRUE

Tags: r, web-scraping, google-trends, gtrendsr

I work with the most recent version of devtools::install_github('PMassicotte/gtrendsR')

Until yesterday evening all was well. Then I got this error message:

```
Error: widget$status_code == 200 is not TRUE
```

code:

```
trend1 = gtrends("google", geo = c(""), time = "2014-07-28 2015-11-23")
```

result:

```
> trend1 = gtrends("google", geo = c(""), time = "2014-07-28 2015-11-23")
Error: widget$status_code == 200 is not TRUE
```

Does anyone know what happend of how to fix?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I came up with the same problem and finally found a solution as well as your question. just in case it can still be of help. you should install the devtools version:

```
devtools::install_github("PMassicotte/gtrendsR")
```

in case you do not have `curl` package installed you should do it manually before installing `gtrendsR`

Comment: I keep getting the same error message. Any updated ideas what to do? Would be great!

Comment: This worked for me: "in case you do not have curl package installed you should do it manually before installing gtrendsR"